# .split() a string containing the characters "++"

Tags: java, regex, split

Suppose I have this block of code:

```
String x = "Hello ++ World!";
if(x.contains(" ++ "))
    System.out.println(x.split(" ++ ")[0]);
```

Why is it that when I execute this code I receive the output:

- `Hello ++ World!` instead of `Hello`?

It obviously has something to do with the `split()`, however, I can't figure it out.

Comment: `split` accepts a regular expression. The `+` character is a character with a special meaning in the context of regular expressions.

Comment: `String.split(String)` treats the parameter as a regular expression where `+` has a special meaning. Try `split(" \\+\\+ ")` or `split(Pattern.quote(" ++ "))` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) uses Regex for the split.
Your expression `" ++ "` is a Regex and the `+` character has a special meaning. From the documentation:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

You have to escape these characters:

```
System.out.println(x.split(" \\+\\+ ")[0]);
```

Comment: Using Pattern.quote like Thomas recommended above is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Because `++` it's interpreted as a regular expression. You need to escape it with backslash. Try this:

`System.out.println(x.split(" \\+\\+ ")[0]);`

Comment: Well, that doesn't work, because \ is also an escape character in Java, so you need to escape the backslashes as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am sure I have added 2 backslashes though..

Answer (score -1):

Split method uses a regexp as argument, you should escape special characters like `+`. Try something like:

```
    String x = "Hello ++ World!";
    if(x.contains(" ++ "))
        System.out.println(x.split("\\s\\+\\+\\s")[0]);
```